# how to make upload of more than 3 pictures in laravel

Tags: laravel

I will make more than 3 photo upload forms.

how can I upload more than 1 photo on the form and controller on Laravel 6?

Answer (score 0):

```
     if($request->hasFile('product_image')){
        $image = $request->file('product_image');

        $fileNameToStore1 = array();

        foreach($request->file('product_image') as $image)
        {
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            $fileNameToStore1 = 'product_images/'.$request->designer_id.'/'.$filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image   //storage/product_images/2/Capture_1585646203.PNG
            //$path = $image->storeAs('product_images/'.$request->designer_id, $fileNameToStore);

            $image->move(public_path('product_images/'.$request->designer_id), $fileNameToStore);

            $requestData = [
                'product_id' => $last_id,
                'img_url' => $fileNameToStore1
            ];

            $product_images = product_images::insert($requestData);
        }
    } else {
        $fileNameToStore1 = '';
    }
```